# determine encoding of content scraped from xpath. convert to unicode

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, unicode

I used the firefox xpath extractor to extract the following snippet from this website: `http://www.zdic.net/z/19/js/5DCD.htm`

The part I'm looking for is `丨フ丨ノ一丨ノ丶フノ一ノ丨フ一一ノフフ丶`

The [xpath extractor add on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/) served me up the following `id('z_i_t2_bis')`

I input that to the [scrapy shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#creating-a-project) with this command: `response.selector.xpath("id('z_i_t2_bis')").extract()`

It returned this:

```
[u'<span id="z_i_t2_bis" title="\u7ad6\u6298\u7ad6\u6487\u6a2a\u7ad6\u6487\u637a\u6298\u6487\u6a2a\u6487\u7ad6\u6298\u6a2a\u6a2a\u6487\u6298\u6298\u637a">\u4e28\u30d5\u4e28\u30ce\u4e00\u4e28\u30ce\u4e36\u30d5\u30ce\u4e00\u30ce\u4e28\u30d5\u4e00\u4e00\u30ce\u30d5\u30d5\u4e36</span>']
```

How can I tell if that's what I want?

It seems to be encoded for HTML, is there a way to put it back to unicode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already unicode. It's just an escaped representation.
So you could check directly for your pattern with the 'in' operator:

```
pattern = u'丨フ丨ノ一丨ノ丶フノ一ノ丨フ一一ノフフ丶'
result = [u'<span id="z_i_t2_bis" title="\u7ad6\u6298\u7ad6\u6487\u6a2a\u7ad6\u6487\u637a\u6298\u6487\u6a2a\u6487\u7ad6\u6298\u6a2a\u6a2a\u6487\u6298\u6298\u637a">\u4e28\u30d5\u4e28\u30ce\u4e00\u4e28\u30ce\u4e36\u30d5\u30ce\u4e00\u30ce\u4e28\u30d5\u4e00\u4e00\u30ce\u30d5\u30d5\u4e36</span>']

if pattern in result[0]:
    print('found')
```